# Why does sitecore ignores default value 0 by type integer?

Tags: c#, sitecore, sitecore6, sitecore7

I'm using sitecore. For a project I have created a template with a simple type integer field. This integer field has default value of 0.

When I create a new item based on this template the value 0 (default value), it is not displayed. By changing the default value to 1 (for example) it is displayed. Is there anyone who knows how to fix this issue?

Thanks a lot.

Jordy

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Sitecore** does NOT ignore default value `0`. The value '0' IS stored in **Sitecore** for `Integer` field it's just not displayed by this field as this is a default value for `int` type (or maybe `long` cause from what I know the value is parsed to `long`).

If you change to show `Raw values` the value will be displayed.

And if you access this field value from the code, you will get `0`.

Comment: I see indeed when i turn raw values on the 0 value, but that's not very friendly for the Content Editors.

Comment: I agree, it's not intuitive. Don't know why this field works like this. Maybe the answer is "Nothing is 0"? Just guessing though...

Answer (score 2):

That is really weird.
I can reproduce it with the latest revision of Sitecore 7.2 as well.

What I suggest that you contact Sitecore Support about this issue cause it might be a bug.

In the meantime, just use a `Number` field instead of an `Integer`.
For some reason it does work correctly with that field type.
Only side-effect is that it will accept decimal values as well...

You can solve this by adding this regular expression to the `Validation` field of the field item: `^\d+$`

[image]

Comment: I'm not familiar with Sitecore, but unless it uses a different regular expression syntax from anything I've seen, `^\d$` would only accept a single digit.

Comment: A number field is not an option, because the Content Editors can make failures. I found a possible solution to validate a single line text with a regular expression: ^(0|[1-9]\d*)$, but that's not the way i prefer.

Comment: What do you mean by "Content Editors can make failures"? Even if you use an Integer field, the value is stored as text in the database. If you add that regular expression validation to a Number field, you basically have the same field as you would have with an Integer.

Answer (score 1):

Sitecore does not ignore the value 0. It just does not show it to the user that's all but its value will be stored as 0 in the database and if you access that field's value from the code it will give you 0 as the result. If you want to check you can view the dbbrowser where it will show the value as 0. To view the dbbrowser go to

`<URL Address>`/sitecore/admin/login.aspx

login as sitecore\ `<user id>`

go to the item and check the value of the field